# bootstrap адаптивность и абсолютное позиционирование

Tags: css, bootstrap

Добрый день, объясните, пожалуйста, такие вопросы, пытаюсь делать простенький шаблон: http://comsaaxov.ho.ua/sedona/

Возникла пара нюансов.

- При изменении размера экрана отступы верхнего меню не уменьшаются (ставил их в %, сейчас стоят px, `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12` тоже назначал).
- Как задавать размеры и отступы при абсолютном позиционировании, чтобы расположение блока и размеры менялись в зависимости от разрешения экрана? (ну, то есть, понятно, что есть медиа-запросы, но не каждые же 30 пикселей изменения разрешения подправлять положение абсолютного блока?)

Answer (score 1):

На этой странице стоит тег Bootstrap, а Вы почему-то пытаетесь решить проблему используя чистый CSS.

> При изменении размера экрана отступы верхнего меню не уменьшаются

Верхнее меню (как и нижнее) в этом фреймворке реализуется компонентом [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), при использовании которого проблем с отступами обычно не возникает

> Как задавать размеры и отступы при абсолютном позиционировании, чтобы расположение блока и размеры менялись в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

В первую очередь нужно пытаться найти стандартный компонент. Если такого не существует, искать скрипт, расширяющий возможности фреймворка. Использовать медиа-запросы рекомендуется только в исключительных ситуациях, когда не нашлось совсем ничего подходящего.